# What are the parameters for createPeriodicWave() in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-audio, web-audio-api

```
var ctx = new webkitAudioContext();
    pw = ctx.createWaveshaper();
```

Every time I use the CreatePeriodicWave() in Google Chrome I just get

```
SyntaxError: Failed to construct 'PeriodicWave': invalid real array
```

What do I put in the function to avoid this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`createPeriodicWave` expects two arguments -- both are `Float32Array` instances -- that specify coefficients of a Fourier Series. The first is the `real` portion, which is an array of cosine terms. The second, `imag`, represents sine terms.

Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve, though? I have a feeling that just knowing that the args are `Float32Array` probably isn't going to be that big of a help.

Comment: So do I have to add arguments like this `[Math.cos(0),Math.cos(1)...],[Math.sin(0),Math.sin(1)...]`?

Comment: Sort of. But they have to be instances of `Float32Array`, not instances of `Array`. Again, if you tell me specifically what you want to accomplish, I might be able to give you a bit more help.

Answer (score 21):

To get a PeriodicWave, the code would be as follows:

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext();
var realCoeffs = new Float32Array([0,0]); // No DC offset or cosine fundamental freq
var imagCoeffs = new Float32Array([0,1]); // sine of amplitude 1 at fundamental freq (First imaginary coeff is ignored)
var wave = context.createPeriodicWave(realCoeffs, imagCoeffs); // will be a simple sine wave
```

You can then use the PeriodicWaveform `wave` in an `OscillatorNode`:

```
var osc = context.createOscillator();
osc.setPeriodicWave(wave);
osc.frequency.value = 440;
osc.connect(context.destination);
osc.start(0);
```

You can read more about the coefficients by looking up "Fourier Series". The short of it is this:

Let's say *`f`* is your fundamental frequency (equivalent to `osc.frequency.value`)

For the real coefficients, `Kr`:

- `Kr[0]` is the DC offset (the amplitude of the "wave" created by cos(0 *`f`* t))
- `Kr[1]` is the amplitude of the cosine wave at the fundamental frequency (cos(1 *`f`* t))
- `Kr[2]` is the amplitude of the cosine wave at the 2<sup>nd</sup> harmonic (cos(2 *`f`* t))
- etc...

For the imaginary coefficients it's the same, except they are sine waves instead, and the 0<sup>th</sup> coefficent is ignored, since it would be the amplitude of the wave `sin(0*t)`, which is 0 for all t.

#### Sawtooth wave example:

Note: If you really just want a sawtooth, you can generate it by just setting the `type` property in an oscillator node to "sawtooth", but if that option were hypothetically not available, this is how you might do it.

For a sawtooth wave, you can see the coefficients here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSawtoothWave.html

A sawtooth has DC offset of 1/2 (i.e. the first real coefficient) - the rest of the real coefficients are 0 - and imaginary coefficients of the form 1 / (nπ). So in order to produce a sawtooth you would replace the lines

```
var realCoeffs = new Float32Array([0,0]);
var imagCoeffs = new Float32Array([0,1]);
```

above, with the following:

```
var numCoeffs = 64; // The more coefficients you use, the better the approximation
var realCoeffs = new Float32Array(numCoeffs);
var imagCoeffs = new Float32Array(numCoeffs);

realCoeffs[0] = 0.5;
for (var i = 1; i < numCoeffs; i++) { // note i starts at 1
    imagCoeffs[i] = 1 / (i * Math.PI);
}
```

Comment: Can you do an example for a sawtooth wave?

Comment: *"For the real coefficients, `Kr` [...] For the real coefficients it's the same"* -- didn't you mean *real* coefficients first, and *imag* coefficients second?

Comment: It looks like DC offset cannot be edited based on the spec: "The first element (index 0) is the DC-offset of the periodic waveform. Implementations MUST set it to zero when computing the waveform."(https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-periodicwaveoptions-real)